# Scope in TypeScript/angularJS HTTP GET request

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angularjs-scope

I'm new to typescript and angular.js and I'm struggling with a http get request.
I'm using [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) for angular's type definitions.

My controller code looks like this:

```
module game.Controller {
    'use strict';

    export interface IGameScope extends ng.IScope {
        vm: GameCtrl;
    }

    export class GameCtrl {

        private bonus: any;
        private http: any;

        constructor($scope: IGameScope, $http: ng.IHttpService, $location: ng.ILocationService) { 
            $scope.vm = this;
            this.http = $http;
        }

        doBet() {
            this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/db').success(function(data: any, status: any) { 
                    this.bonus = data;
                }
            );
        }
    }

}
```

and my view like this:

```
<button ng-click="vm.doBet()">bet</button>
<div><span>bonus: {{ vm.bonus }}</span></div>
```

the view-model binding works fine, when I change the bonus variable without the http request. But when I try to update the bonus variable in the success function of the get request, I get following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'bonus' of undefined
```

How can I achieve to update variables in the success function?

I also would appreciate any suggestion, if there's a better/cleaner way or practice to update data on requests

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can easily be done using TypeScript's lambda expression:

```
doBet() {
    this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/db').success(
        (data, status) => this.bonus = data
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you have some more explanation on this topic? E.g. a why we have to use the lambda expression here?

Comment: in normal js you would have e.g. `this.http.get('url').success(function(data, status) { ... });`, so `this` is not visible in success function. the lamba expression as shown above autmatically compiles to `var _this = this; this.http.get('url').success(function(data, status) { _this.member = "something"; });`, so `this` is made visible in scope through the helper variable `_this`. hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

`this` in `this.bonus = data;` actually refers to the callback function inside `success`.

Instead you can do like this: `$scope.vm.bonus = data;`

Comment: this doesn't work, since `$scope` is only visible in constructor and not in the `doBet()` function.

Comment: @3x14159265 Move `doBet()` into your constructor and declare it as a method on `$scope`: `$scope.doBet = function() { ... };`, or simply pass `$scope` into `doBet()`.

Comment: @3x14159265 Of the 2 options, I would preferably move `doBet` inside the controller and declare it on the scope.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the method in the constructor in order to access the $scope like this:

```
constructor($scope: IGameScope, $http: ng.IHttpService, $location: ng.ILocationService) {
    $scope.vm = this;
    this.http = $http;

    $scope.doBet = function() {
        this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/db').success(function (data: any, status: any) {
            $scope.bonus = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.piotrwalat.net/using-typescript-with-angularjs-and-web-api/) about using AngularJS with Typescript.

Comment: thanks, I already read this tutorial. But is it really best practice to define all scope functions in the controller? furthermore, I'm binding the `$scope.vm` variable to my controller instance to omitte the need of binding every single scope variable to my controller variables. so IMHO in this case, there would be no enhancement on using the binding `$scope.vm = this;`.

Comment: @3x14159265 I think it is really over killing to use TypeScript, it complicated the JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used typescript, but to me it looks like a closure/scope issue. Your success call back is running asynchronously so the value of `this` is different inside. Try binding the function call back with `this`.

```
this.http.get('http://localhost:9000/db').success(angular.bind(this,
    function(data: any, status: any) {this.bonus = data;});
```

Comment: This is not necessary in typescript. See 3x14159265's answer.